# PHP - How to carry on the SESSION variables after a form submit

Tags: php, html

Im having issues  while using the SESSION variables. Im planning to add data to a SQL each time the user hit "Submit" on the generar.php script. I'm also counting on the login data of the first pag index.html here is where im having issues, whenever i hit "Submit" it will clean the variables. I checked several 
forums looking for an answer but still i dont have an answer. Any ideas?

index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Creacion de receta</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
<body>
<br>
<div style="text-align: center;"><img style="width: 125px; height: 125px;" alt="Rpi" src="large_logo_white.png"><br></div>
<br>
<table style="text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<form method="post" action="generar.php">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Codigo del Medico</td>
<td><input name="v_codigo"><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cedula del paciente</td>
<td><input name="v_cedula"><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Enviar</td>
<td align="right"><input name="submit" value="Enviar" type="submit"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</form>
</table>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

generar.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Creacion de receta</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Medicamento</td>
<td>
<select name="v_meds"><option>Seleccionar</option><option>Rojo</option><option>Verde</option><option>Azul</option><option>Amarillo</option><option>Blanco</option><option>Negro</option></select>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Via</td>
<td>
<select name="v_via"><option>Seleccionar</option><option>Oral</option><option>Rectal</option><option>Nasal</option><option>Otica</option><option>Oftalmica</option><option>Vaginal</option><option>Topica</option></select>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Frecuencia</td>
<td>
<select name="v_frec"><option>Seleccionar</option><option>6</option><option>8</option><option>12</option><option>24</option></select>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Duracion</td>
<td>
<select name="v_dur"><option>Seleccionar</option><option>5</option><option>7</option><option>15</option><option>30</option><option>PRN10</option><option>PRN20</option><option>PRN30</option></select>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Enviar</td>
<td align="right"><input name="submit" value="Enviar" type="submit"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2" rowspan="1"><a href="view.php">Ver historial de recetas</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</form>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
if (isset($_REQUEST['v_codigo']) || isset($_REQUEST['v_cedula'])) { 
 $codigo = $_REQUEST['v_codigo'];
 $cedula = $_REQUEST['v_cedula'];
}
 $_SESSION['sesion_codigo'] = $codigo;
 $_SESSION['sesion_cedula'] = $cedula;

 //$codigo1 = $_SESSION['sesion_codigo'];
 //$cedula1 = $_SESSION['sesion_cedula'];
 $tabla = 'p'.$cedula1;
 
 print 'Codigo: ' . $codigo . '<br/>';
 print 'Cedula: ' . $cedula . '<br/>';
 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // collect value of input field
    $name1 = $_POST['v_meds']; 
 $name2 = $_POST['v_via'];
 $name3 = $_POST['v_frec'];
 $name4 = $_POST['v_dur'];
    if ($name1 == 'Seleccionar' || $name2 == 'Seleccionar' || $name3 == 'Seleccionar' || $name4 == 'Seleccionar') {
        echo "Receta contiene errores, favor llenar correctamente el formulario.<br/>";
    } else {
        echo $name1 . $name2 . $name3 . $name4;
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 1:
I change the session_start(); to the very begining of the html file. But had same result. The first time i select the variables $codigo and $cedula they are correctl setup, when i click on submit button they disapear. The idea is that after clicking the submit button I keep the losgin data to send serveral requests in a row.

Below the images of each step. Thanks again to all who take time to answer.

Login data: 
codigovar
cedulavar

[First time the page is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eouzV.png)
[After clicking the submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdIaq.png)

EDIT 2: I'm also using @RamRaider code suggestions to fill the variables only if they are populated.

Comment: to use sessions you need to include `session_start();` at the top of the php script - have you done so?

Comment: yes! <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

Comment: you are trying to say that session vars gets destroy after form sumit ??

Comment: Have you tried using this `echo $_SESSION['sesion_codigo'];
 echo $_SESSION['sesion_cedula'];` to see your session variables?

Comment: The first time i do see the variables, after the submit, i just see them as blank.

Answer (score 0):

You should start session  in top

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

because in your code it will show error like header already sent
when we start session in `php` there should not be output to page before

```
session_start();
```

So your code should be something like this:-

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

Comment: Had the same result byt switching session_start() to the very begining. thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Pritamkumar But you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem, I believe, was that none of the `SELECT` elements had `OPTION` values. The call to `session_start()` should also be before any html output - so typically right at the very top of the script. Also, the call tha sets the session variables could set blank values as it was - a test to ensure the values are present before setting would be a good idea.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    /* utility function to debug session and request data */
    function pre($data,$title){
        echo "<h1>".strtoupper($title)."</h1><pre>".print_r($data,true)."</pre>";
    }
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
      <title>Creacion de receta</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
   </head>
   <body>
    <?php
        if( isset( $_SESSION['sesion_codigo'], $_SESSION['sesion_cedula'] ) ){
            echo '<h1>Debug session variables</h1>';
            pre($_SESSION,'session');
            pre($_POST,'post');

        }
    ?>

      <form method="post">
        <table>
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <td>Medicamento</td>
                   <td>
                      <select name="v_meds">
                         <option value=''>Seleccionar
                         <option value='Rojo'>Rojo
                         <option value='Verde'>Verde
                         <option value='Azul'>Azul
                         <option value='Amarillo'>Amarillo
                         <option value='Blanco'>Blanco
                         <option value='Negro'>Negro
                      </select>
                      <br>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Via</td>
                   <td>
                      <select name="v_via">
                         <option value=''>Seleccionar
                         <option value='Oral'>Oral
                         <option value='Rectal'>Rectal
                         <option value='Nasal'>Nasal
                         <option value='Otica'>Otica
                         <option value='Oftalmica'>Oftalmica
                         <option value='Vaginal'>Vaginal
                         <option value='Topica'>Topica
                      </select>
                      <br>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Frecuencia</td>
                   <td>
                      <select name="v_frec">
                         <option value=''>Seleccionar
                         <option value='6'>6
                         <option value='8'>8
                         <option value='12'>12
                         <option value='24'>24
                      </select>
                      <br>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Duracion</td>
                   <td>
                      <select name="v_dur">
                         <option value=''>Seleccionar
                         <option value='5'>5
                         <option value='7'>7
                         <option value='15'>15
                         <option value='30'>30
                         <option value='PRN10'>PRN10
                         <option value='PRN20'>PRN20
                         <option value='PRN30'>PRN30
                      </select>
                      <br>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>Enviar</td>
                   <td align="right"><input name="submit" value="Enviar" type="submit"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2" rowspan="1">
                        <a href="view.php">Ver historial de recetas</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>
      </form>

    <?php
        $codigo = !empty( $_REQUEST['v_codigo'] ) ? $_REQUEST['v_codigo'] : false;
        $cedula = !empty( $_REQUEST['v_cedula'] ) ? $_REQUEST['v_cedula'] : false;

        if( $codigo & $cedula ){

            $_SESSION['sesion_codigo'] = $codigo;
            $_SESSION['sesion_cedula'] = $cedula;

            $tabla = 'p'.$cedula1;

            printf( "Codigo: %s<br />Cedula: %s<br />", $codigo, $cedula );
        }


        if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) {


            $name1 = !empty( $_POST['v_meds'] ) ? $_POST['v_meds'] : false; 
            $name2 = !empty( $_POST['v_via'] ) ? $_POST['v_via'] : false;
            $name3 = !empty( $_POST['v_frec'] ) ? $_POST['v_frec'] : false;
            $name4 = !empty( $_POST['v_dur'] ) ? $_POST['v_dur'] : false;


            if( $name1 && $name2 && $name3 && $name4 ){
                $message=$name1 . $name2 . $name3 . $name4;
            } else {
                $message="Receta contiene errores, favor llenar correctamente el formulario.<br/>";
            }

            echo $message;
        }

    ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, although I still see the same results. The session variables are set the first time. Whenever i click the submit button, the variables get cleaned up.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the failure you mention. Using the above ( as `generar.php` ) after having created a replica of your `index.html` page the form submits OK to generar.php and sets the session variables. On subsequent submissions of the form on generar.php the session variables maintain their values

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```